# Have compute-engine vm run scripts when started gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run a NodeJS server on gcloud. I used the gcloud metadata to build a startup script. 
The script does not appear to be run because i see no evidence of it in the logs nor my server coming online.

When i run the startup script command after connecting using SSH, everything works fine.

Is there something i have to do in the gcloud shell(not the vm) to have that script run when the VM starts? Or is the startup commands located in some file?

I have tried a few different things that i saw on here, but none of the were for Debian 9 (stretch) and the others did not work.

I looked for some kind of *commands to execute* script in /etc and /var but couldn't find anything online.

I also looked for /etc/rc.local and it didn't exist.

According to another post on here there is supposed to be a file called google.startup.script but i couldn't find it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Start by posting your script. 2) Show how you configured the script to run.

Comment: Output from the execution of startup scripts is also logged to the "Serial Console" of your Compute Engine VM which you can view in the Cloud Console in the details of your instance.

Comment: My scripts contain alot of sensetive information. If i were to omit it most of my script would be gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure a script to run when VM starts up through instance metadata:

```
gcloud compute instances create example-instance \
    --metadata-from-file startup-script=examples/scripts/install.sh
```

If you need this on a wider scale you can specify **project metadata** and **instance metadata** inherits them. Please refer to the following link for further information.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

Comment: Let me try that. Thank you!

Comment: How do I do that with an existing vm?

Comment: checkout this page: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata. Scroll to `Updating metadata on a running instance` which should give you the steps to do this.